# Error when Requiring Twilio Voice SDK Javascript

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, velo

I have included (via npm) the twilio/voice-sdk package (v.2.1.0) into a project. When I include the following code (as shown in many examples):

```
const Device = require('@twilio/voice-sdk').Device;
```

I get a console error stating:

"Cannot find module 'events' in '@twilio/audioplayer/es5'".  I am trying to import this onto the client side, not server.

I get this whether I use require or import.

As an attempt around this, I have also include the node package @twilio/audioplayer, but to no avail.  Kind of stuck as to what is going on here.

I am trying to use this on a Wix (or Velo more specifically) project.  Hoping to create a dialer that can both answer and instigate phone calls on a site that already exists on that platform.

I have installed both of the above npm packages into my project, but get he above enumerated error.

Any ideas from the Internet?

Additional Information:
If I add the 'require' on the server side I do not get the same error.  I was going to try this and then do an async call to the server to get my Device object.  However, the Twilio Device SDK package utilizes the Window object, which of course does not exist on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The @twilio/audioplayer package uses the "events" module. This module is available in Node.js and when applications are bundled with something like Webpack is polyfilled.

I haven't used Velo, but I assume they are bundling differently in a way that doesn't add polyfills for this. I'd recommend installing the [events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) npm module to your project too. That should provide the `EventEmitter` that the library is using for the browser environment and stop this error.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting an answer out so quickly.  Alas, it didn't solve the problem.  I was afraid that it was going to be an issue with how Velo bundles things.  Sadly, Velo doesn't seem to offer much in the way of support as far as asking questions goes to see how they approach this or to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further. Could this [Velo forum](https://www.wix.com/velo/forum) help as a place to ask questions like this too? They also seem to have a [Discord server](https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/join-our-discord-server-1).

Comment: I love helpful people of the internet.  Thank you for the links to the Velo Forum and the Discord Server.  I'll post the question out to those platforms.  If I get something back, I'll answer it here just in case anyone else decides to do this.

Comment: That would be great, good luck finding an answer and I look forward to seeing you share it back here once you do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I can import Device, but cannot construct it. The problem I had was that the bundler (in my case Vite) doesn't have a polyfill to run some functions inside the @twilio/voice-sdk.

The solution in my case was by installing polyfill on Vite.

Here is how:

First, install these packages:

```
npm i @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill --save-dev
```

Then add the polyfill config to your vite.config.js. Here is link of the code: https://medium.com/@ftaioli/using-node-js-builtin-modules-with-vite-6194737c2cd2.

Because I use React, I still need to add plugins: [react()] inside the polyfill config. So it becomes something like:

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
// rest of the polyfill config
})
```

Now you can do:

```
import { Device } from "@twilio/voice-sdk";
new Device(token);
```